# Docker API application, in ASP.Net builds successfully from Visual Studio Only, not from console like git-bash/powershell

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, docker

Docker build command from IDE:

```
12>docker build -f "D:\sampleproject\Src\Services\Example\Example.API\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t exampleapi:dev --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=Example.API" "D:\sampleproject"
```

Docker run command from IDE:

```
12>docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\johnd\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "D:\sampleproject\Src\Services\Example\Example.API:/app" -v "D:\sampleproject:/src/" -v "C:\Users\johnd\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\johnd\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Users\johnd\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -P --name Example.API --entrypoint tail exampleapi:dev -f /dev/null
```

Building and running, from command prompt, keeps container in running state. Endpoints are not accessible. For example, curl *http://localhost:32823/swagger/index.html* returns empty reply from server.

```
docker build -f dockerfile-example --force-rm -t contentocr.azurecr.io/exampleapi:lore --label "com.content.created-by=git-bash" .
```

```
docker run -dt  -v "C:\Users\johnd\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -P --name Example.API --entrypoint tail contentocr.azurecr.io/exampleapi:lore -f /dev/null
```

From inside container, *curl http://localhost:80/swagger/index.html* returns connections refused error message text.

Docker file is as below

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Src/Services/Example/Example.API/Example.API.csproj", "Src/Services/Example/Example.API/"]
COPY ["Src/Dependencies/Dependency/Dependent.csproj", "Src/Dependencies/Dependency/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Src/Services/Example/Example.API/Example.API.csproj"

RUN dotnet restore "Src/Dependencies/Dependency/Dependent.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Src/Services/Example/Example.API"
RUN dotnet build "Example.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Example.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY devops/SSL/UserSecrets /root/.microsoft/usersecrets
COPY devops/SSL/ASP.NET/Https/Example.API.tmpcert /root/.aspnet/https/Example.API.pfx
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Example.API.dll"]
```

How can I build and execute container from *git-bash/power/cmd* shells?

Answer (score 0):

An update to docker file to include Visual Studio volume mount resolves this issue as below like *-- Section #Volume mount explicit copy --*

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Src/Services/Example/Example.API/Example.API.csproj", "Src/Services/Example/Example.API/"]
COPY ["Src/Dependencies/Dependency/Dependent.csproj", "Src/Dependencies/Dependency/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Src/Services/Example/Example.API/Example.API.csproj"

RUN dotnet restore "Src/Dependencies/Dependency/Dependent.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Src/Services/Example/Example.API"
RUN dotnet build "Example.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Example.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

#Volume mount explicit copy
#COPY /c/Users/johnd/vsdbg/vs2017u5 /remote_debugger 
COPY ./Src/Services/Example/Example.API /app
COPY . /src/
COPY ./devops/SSL/UserSecrets /root/.microsoft/usersecrets
COPY ./devops/SSL/ASP.NET/Https/Example.API.tmpcert /root/.aspnet/https/Example.API.pfx
#COPY C:\\Users\\johnd\\.nuget\\packages\\ /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages 

ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1 
ENV ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true 
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80 
ENV NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages 
ENV NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Example.API.dll"]
```